# How do I sort this circle list?

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to figure out how to make a sorted Circle List class. I have an unsorted class, but I seem to be having issues sorting the list. I have tried figuring it out with the help of a sorted list class i have used in other programs. I think that I need to use the compareTo() method, but I can't seem to figure out exactly how to do it.

```
public class CRefUnsortedList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements ListInterface<T>
{
    protected int numElements;
    protected LLNode<T> currentPos;
    protected boolean found;
    protected LLNode<T> location;
    protected LLNode<T> previous;

    protected LLNode<T> list;

    public CRefUnsortedList()
    {
        numElements = 0;
        list = null;
        currentPos = null;
    }

    public void reset()
    {
        if (list != null)
        {
            currentPos = list.getLink();
        }
    }

    public T getNext()
    {
        T next = currentPos.getInfo();
        currentPos = currentPos.getLink();
        return next;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String listString = "List:\n";
        if(list != null)
        {
            LLNode<T> prevNode = list;
            do
            {
                listString = listString + " " + prevNode.getLink().getInfo() + "\n";
                prevNode = prevNode.getLink();
            }while(prevNode != list);
        }
        return listString;
    }

    protected void find(T target)
    {
        location = list;
        found = false;

        if(list != null)
        {
            do
            {
                previous = location;
                location = location.getLink();

                if(location.getInfo().equals(target))
                {
                    found = true;
                }
            }while((location != list) && !found);
        }
    }

    public boolean remove (T element)
    {
        find(element);
        if(found)
        {
            if(list == list.getLink())
            {
                list = null;
            }
            else
            {
                if (previous.getLink() == list)
                {
                    list = previous;
                }
                else
                {
                    previous.setLink(location.getLink());
                }
                numElements--;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

    public T get(T element)
    {
        find(element);
        if (found)
        {
            return location.getInfo();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void add(T element)
    {
        LLNode<T> newNode = new LLNode<T>(element);
        if(list == null)
        {
            list = newNode;
            newNode.setLink(list);
        }
        else
        {
            newNode.setLink(list.getLink());
            list.setLink(newNode);
            list = newNode;
        }
        numElements++;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return numElements;
    }

    public boolean contains(T element)
    {
        find(element);
        return found;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that would depend on the `Circle` class. What is the sort criteria?

Comment: This seems like a lot of work. Why not just extend ArrayList, and use standard collections sorting. Then all you'd have to do is override get() and use modulo math to make retrieving elements act "circular."

Comment: It just needs to sort the objects, such as a sort the strings alphabetically.

Comment: I have to use the ciruclar linked list because that's what I'm studying right now